# What should be the scope and usage guidance excerpt for The Adventures of Pinocchio?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

So a new tag was created [the-adventures-of-pinocchio](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-adventures-of-pinocchio) (1 question asked).

As of now there is no usage guidance for it.

*The adventures of Pinocchio* has a whole list of adaptations in all forms of media like Movies, Theatre, TV, Musicals etc. So what shall be the scope of this tag? Should it cover all the adaptations and media?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*The Adventures of Pinocchio* has had many adaptations over the years but most of the recent ones have simply been named *Pinocchio*. I suggest we create one tag for the "Pinocchio universe" that encompasses all of the works simply named [pinocchio](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pinocchio). It's usage guidance should then be something like:

> For questions about works about the story of Pinocchio from the original 1883 book "The Adventures of Pinocchio" to the 1940 film "Pinocchio" by Disney and beyond.

If we get too many questions on Pinocchio, which I doubt, we can always start creating work specific tags.